# Why is the texture scale changing randomly between frames in my animation?

Tags: texturing

I'm trying to render an animation, but I've happened upon a strange texture quirk for which I can't seem to easily determine the cause. Every so often, one of the frames will render with the texture scaled differently:

[image]
[image]

(**frame 9** on the left rendering without issue and **frame 10** on the right with the problem)

- I am using Blender v2.83.3 on Windows 10 (64-bit)
- I have tried switching from GPU to CPU rendering in Cycles, but that made no difference
- This happens both when rendering as an animation and rendering stills
- The bug does not show up when viewport shading is set to rendered

[Here](https://files.quickmediasolutions.com/downloads/texture-bug.blend) is a link to the .blend file.

Comment: Hello, you forgot to pack the texture in the file you provided (File > External Data > Pacj into file) so I couldn't witness it... By the way, instead of using an Edge Split modifier, you should enable "Auto Smooth" within the mesh properties

Comment: Whoops! I have uploaded the correct .blend with the missing texture. Sorry about that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has to do with the *Motion Blur*'s *Shutter* value, it is set to 0.5, if you choose 0.4 or 0.6 it works, I can't tell exactly why though  ;)

Comment: I couldn't find a value that would cause _none_ of the frames to have this problem, so I ended up disabling motion blur.